# How to set lastPage.nextCursor in useInfiniteQuery hook of react Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

My Infinite query hook looks like this

```
const {
    data,
    error,
    isSuccess,
    hasNextPage,
    fetchNextPage,
    isFetchingNextPage
  }=useInfiniteQuery(
    'test',
    ({ pageParam = 1 }) => fetchData(pageParam, 14),
    {
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage: any, allPages: any) => {
        console.log('endCursor', lastPage.nextCursor);
        if (hasNextPage) {
          console.log('Returning from keep fetching', lastPage.nextCursor);
          return lastPage.nextCursor;
        }
        return undefined;
      }
    }
  );
```

My fetch function looks like this

```
const fetchData = async (page = 1, pageSize: any, variables?: string) => {
    console.log('Inside fetch data for new schema');
    const res = await graphQLClient.request(
      QUERY,
      variables,
      requestHeaders
    );
    console.log('res', res);
    return {
      pages: res.getCustomerLibrary.books.edges,
      hasNextPage: res.data.books.pageInfo.hasNextPage,
      lastPage: { nextCursor: res.data.books.pageInfo.endCursor },
      nextPage: res.data
    };
  };
```

Data is coming properly, but my question is how do I update the lastPage.nextCursor so that I can use it in useInfiniteQuery hook.

Right now its coming undefined for all the pages.

Also, am I doing something wrong, because the data is not being returned properly, whatever I am returning from my fetchData function everything goes in pages variable of data, what I want is:

- pages variable returned from fetch function should go to pages
- hasNextPage returned from fetch function should populate the hasNextPage hook of infiniteQuery
- lastPage.nextCursor should be populated in pageParam so that I can use it to fetch nextpage

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `hasNextPage` in the `queryFn` because it's a result returned from `useInfiniteQuery`. `hasNextPage` is derived from what you return from `getNextPageParam`, so this would be circular.

Your `fetchData` function returns a `nextCursor`, so why not just check for this? If it's `undefined`, there will be no next page, so you return `undefined`, otherwise, you return the `nextCursor`.

Also note that `lastPage` you're getting into the `getNextPageParam` is exactly of the type that your queryFn returns. You would see that if you wouldn't overwrite the types with `any`. So with your result structure, the code would need to be:

```
getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
  if (lastPage.hasNextPage) {
    return lastPage.lastPage.nextCursor;
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

the double `lastPage` looks weird but that's what your `queryFn` returns. Of course you can change that, flatten the structure and then adapt `getNextPageParam`.